# recyclerview vieholder is not getting recycled

Tags: android, memory-management, android-recyclerview, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

developing an image picker using recyclerview with all images in devices for an android app, facing an issue when user scroll through images its memory usage keeps increasing eventually if lots of images there is oom exception, have searched for this issue over the internet, have applied several techniques but it is of little use, i have seen other app(whatsapp, olx) its picker scrolling is nice and no oom, i also tried dump heap in android studio to detect memory leakage, i found that there are as many viewholders as number of images, its not being recycled, am not able to find the reason, please help me in detecting the issue, attaching code..

```
/** adapter class for grid recyclerview*/
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList;
    private Context context;
    private List<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<>(3);
    private List<Integer> positionList = new ArrayList<>(3);
    int count = 0;
    RequestOptions options;
    RequestBuilder glide;
    RequestManager glideMain;
    int imgWidth;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList, RequestOptions options, RequestBuilder<Bitmap> glide, RequestManager glideMain, int imgWidth) {
    this.galleryList = galleryList;
    this.context = context;
    this.options = options;
    this.glide = glide;
    this.glideMain = glideMain;
    this.imgWidth = imgWidth;
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull ViewHolder holder) {
        holder.img.setOnClickListener(null);
        holder.img.setColorFilter(null);
        holder.img.setImageDrawable(null);
        if(holder.title.getText().toString().equals("1")){

        }
        //holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(null);
        glideMain.clear(holder.img);
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
}

@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull ViewHolder holder) {
  /*  holder.img.setOnClickListener(null);
    holder.img.setColorFilter(null);*/
        holder.img.setImageDrawable(null);
        // holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(null);
        glideMain.clear(holder.img);
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
}

@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder) {
  /*  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.handleThumbnail(view);
        }
    });*/
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
}

public ArrayList<CreateList> getGalleryList() {
    return galleryList;
}

public void setGalleryList(ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList) {
    this.galleryList = galleryList;
}

public List<Integer> getPositionList() {
    return positionList;
}

public void setPositionList(List<Integer> positionList) {
    this.positionList = positionList;
}

public List<String> getImageUrls() {
    return imageUrls;
}

public void setImageUrls(List<String> imageUrls) {
    this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_layout, viewGroup, false);

    //img.setOnClickListener();

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int pos) {


    glide
            .load(galleryList.get(pos).getImage_Location())
            .thumbnail(0.1F)
            .apply(options)
            .into(viewHolder.img);

    if (positionList.contains(pos)){
        // view not selected
        //viewHolder.parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        viewHolder.title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.title.setText(String.valueOf(positionList.indexOf(pos)+1));
        viewHolder.img.setColorFilter(viewHolder.getColorWithAlpha(Color.GREEN, 0.3f));
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return galleryList.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView title;
    private ImageView img;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.highlightText);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
       /* view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                handleThumbnail(v);
            }
        });*/
       /* img = view.findViewById(R.id.img);*/
        img.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(imgWidth, imgWidth));
        /*img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // This is OnClick of any list Item
                handleThumbnail(v);
            }

        });*/
      /*  img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private Rect rect;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    img.setColorFilter(Color.argb(50, 0, 0, 0));
                    rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
                }
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    img.setColorFilter(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
                }
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    if(!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())){
                        img.setColorFilter(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });*/
    }

    public void handleThumbnail(View v) {
        if(!imageUrls.contains(galleryList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImage_Location())) {
            if(count<3) {
                positionList.add(getAdapterPosition());
                String selectedImgUrl = galleryList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImage_Location();
                imageUrls.add(selectedImgUrl);
                //img.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_background_checked));
                img.setColorFilter(getColorWithAlpha(Color.GREEN, 0.3f));
                //title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //title.setText(String.valueOf(count+1));
                //View viewSelected =  gridRecycler.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView;
                title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                title.setText(String.valueOf(count+1));
                count++;


            } else {
                Toast.makeText().show();
            }
        } else {
            imageUrls.remove(galleryList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImage_Location());
            positionList.remove(new Integer(getAdapterPosition()));
            //imageUrls.remove( Integer.parseInt(title.getText().toString()));
            title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            count--;
           // img.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_background));
            img.setColorFilter(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent(imageUrls, positionList));
        }
    }

    public int getColorWithAlpha(int color, float ratio) {
        int newColor = 0;
        int alpha = Math.round(Color.alpha(color) * ratio);
        int r = Color.red(color);
        int g = Color.green(color);
        int b = Color.blue(color);
        newColor = Color.argb(alpha, r, g, b);
        return newColor;
    }

}
```

activity code using background thread to load data and set in adapter:

```
private class PrepareData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int imgWidth = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels*0.32);
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .override(imgWidth/3)
                .dontAnimate()
                .centerCrop()
                .skipMemoryCache(true);

        final RequestManager glide = Glide.with(gridRecycler.getContext());

        RequestBuilder builder = glide.asBitmap();
        gridRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(gridRecycler.getContext(), 3);

        createLists = getAllFolderImages(this);

        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, createLists, options, builder, glide, imgWidth);

        gridRecycler.addOnScrollListener(new  RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    glide.resumeRequests();
                }
                if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL || newState==AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                    glide.pauseRequests();
                    System.gc();
                }
            }
        });
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gridRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                gridRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                //put the code here that is giving exception
            }
        });

        return null;
    }
}
```

android profiling screen-shot, its visible that viewholder is consuming lots of memory and has lots of instances.
[image]

Comment: Remove your `getItemViewType()` override. As is, it's telling the `RecyclerView` that every single item is a different type, so it won't try to recycle any of them.

Comment: @MikeM. You should post that as an answer even though it's short.  I read through the code looking for a problem (and didn't notice what you spotted) because nobody had posted an answer.

Comment: @nasch I need to find a duplicate, 'cause I'm fairly certain this has been asked and answered before. I don't have time to search right now, though. Lemme know if you know of, or find, one, and I'll mark this as such.

Comment: I did some searching and didn't find a duplicate but it may be out there.

Comment: @Mike M,. Thanks for the help, it resolves the issue, viewholder are now getting recycled. If there are different viewtype with in an adapter, is there any way to recycle those..?

Comment: Unless you somehow signify otherwise – e.g., with `ViewHolder#setIsRecyclable(false)` – items of a given type will be recycled for use with other items of that same type, by default.

Comment: @Mike M. Sorry Mike I did not get, I meant to say if there are multiple views for an adapter of recyclerview, then we have to override getItemViewType method, it would prevent item to recycle, so how should we do it

Comment: Just overriding `getItemViewType()` doesn't cause the items to not be recycled. In this case, it's what you're returning from `getItemViewType()` that's causing the problem. You're returning `position`, and since every item has a unique position, no two items will have the same type, so none of them get recycled. When using multiple `View` types, you generally only have a handful, compared to the full size of your list, so multiple items will have the same type, and can be recycled for each other.

Comment: As a very simplistic example, say you want to alternate item background colors – red, black, red, black, etc. That would require two types, and you would only ever be returning one of two values from `getItemViewType()` – the red type, or the black type. Now, since there are multiple `View`s of each type, whenever a red one goes off-screen, for example, it can be recycled for the next red one coming on-screen, because it has the same type. Do you follow me?

Comment: Thanks Mike, got it, thanks a lot for such a nice explanation to a noob like me.